# Draw a polygon for a given set of waypoints or a line?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, geometry, polygon, jts

[image: Gievn GeoLine]

The above fig show you a geoLine (1 - 11). Each point is a geo-cordinate.

For a given geoLine I need to draw a Polygon (A bounding box) like in the bove image.

This is to find any Point Of Interest (POI) like PARKING, FUEL, RESTURANT near that GeoLine (Path / WayPoints) (20 / 30 mtrs on each side of geoLine. Not more than 50 mtrs.)

I guess Elasticsearch has a function were in you can specify polygon points and it gives what comes inside that polygon. In order to do that i need all points of polygon like in above fig.

Can someone please tell me on how to approach this? Any explanation along with the code will be helpful.

**WayPoints :**

`13.0489062,77.6037472
13.0493921,77.6028423
13.0494861,77.6017586
13.0491692,77.6010208
13.0482264,77.6010494
13.0472498,77.6010711
13.0461878,77.6011007
13.0454626,77.6010805
13.0446403,77.6011248
13.0438409,77.6010804
13.0438986,77.6017758
13.0438545,77.6030737
13.0439865,77.6040809
13.0439203,77.6056271
13.0438668,77.6066616
13.0436551,77.6077865
13.0434993,77.6088242
13.0432396,77.609767
13.0429808,77.6104908
13.0428103,77.6112412
13.0426729,77.6121114
13.0424444,77.6129859
13.0422521,77.6136721
13.0418346,77.6145997
13.0415062,77.6155134
13.0412306,77.6162379
13.0409749,77.6171142
13.0410531,77.6178208
13.0411159,77.618711
13.0411254,77.6195973
13.0410934,77.6203541
13.0412376,77.6215924
13.0412091,77.6223422
13.0410685,77.6234799
13.0404355,77.6241354
13.0398567,77.6245906
13.038993,77.6252223
13.0381411,77.6258873`

**EDIT**: Language is JAVA.

Comment: The Elasticsearch query would be a `geo_shape` query with a `WITHIN` relation, passing the generated polygon as the shape. If you're using Java, you'd be able to create the polygon using JTS (Java Topology Suite)

Comment: @RussCam Have You used JTS? I have not. So any code if you could provide its helpful.

Comment: If I give you some math on how to generate the points for the polygon, would you be able to implement it?

Comment: @willywonkadailyblah I will definetly give it a shot.

Comment: @willywonkadailyblah can you provide some idea on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take two edges defined by three points `P[n-1], P[n]` and `P[n+1]`, havings normals `m1` and `m2` respectively.

[image]
[image]

Let

[image]

Then the normals are

[image]

[image]

Now the distance of `Q` from `P[n]` along `m0` is

[image]

So therefore

[image]

Where `Q'` is the polygon point on the other side.

---

EDIT: C implementation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "bmp.h"

typedef struct v { double x, y; } vec_t;
#define VECT(x, y) (vec_t){x, y}

vec_t v_add(vec_t a, vec_t b) { return VECT(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y); }
vec_t v_sub(vec_t a, vec_t b) { return VECT(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y); }
vec_t v_mul(vec_t v, double c) { return VECT(v.x * c, v.y * c); }
vec_t v_div(vec_t v, double d) { return v_mul(v, 1.0 / d); }
double v_dot(vec_t a, vec_t b) { return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y; }
double v_mag(vec_t a) { return sqrt(a.x * a.x + a.y * a.y); }
vec_t v_nor(vec_t v) { return v_div(v, v_mag(v)); }
vec_t v_prp(vec_t v) { return VECT(-v.y, v.x); }

vec_t get_disp(vec_t i, vec_t j, vec_t k, double d)
{
    vec_t a = v_sub(j, i), b = v_sub(k, j);
    vec_t m1 = v_nor(v_prp(a)), m2 = v_nor(v_prp(b));
    vec_t m0 = v_nor(v_add(m1, m2));
    return v_mul(m0, d / v_dot(m0, m1));
}

void compute_polygon(vec_t* P, vec_t* Q, int N, double d)
{
    int T = 2 * N - 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        vec_t M = get_disp(P[i - 1], P[i], P[i + 1], d);
        Q[i]     = v_add(P[i], M); 
        Q[T - i] = v_sub(P[i], M);
    }
    vec_t A = v_mul(v_nor(v_prp(v_sub(P[1], P[0]))), d);
    vec_t B = v_mul(v_nor(v_prp(v_sub(P[N-1], P[N-2]))), d);
    Q[0] = v_add(P[0], A); Q[T] = v_sub(P[0], A);
    Q[N - 1] = v_add(P[N - 1], B); Q[N] = v_sub(P[N - 1], B);
}

int iround(double c) { return (int)((c > 0.0) ? c+0.5 : c-0.5); }
void draw_line(bmp_t* i, vec_t a, vec_t b, int c)
{
    bmp_aux_draw_line(i, iround(a.x), iround(a.y), iround(b.x), iround(b.y), c);
}
void draw_dot(bmp_t* i, vec_t p, int c)
{
    bmp_aux_draw_dot(i, iround(p.x), iround(p.y), 3, c);
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 5;
    vec_t P[N], Q[2*N];
    P[0] = VECT(30, 30);
    P[1] = VECT(70, 150);
    P[2] = VECT(130, 170);
    P[3] = VECT(190, 240);
    P[4] = VECT(270, 190);
    compute_polygon(P, Q, N, 10.0);
    bmp_t* img = bmp_new(300, 300);
    for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++)
    {
        draw_line(img, P[i], P[i+1], 0);
        draw_dot(img, P[i], 0x0000FF);
    }
    draw_dot(img, P[N-1], 0x0000FF);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2*N-1; i++)
        draw_line(img, Q[i], Q[i + 1], 0xEEEE00);
    draw_line(img, Q[0], Q[2*N-1], 0xEEEE00);
    bmp_write(img, "a.bmp");
    bmp_free(img);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Points at (30, 30), (70, 150), (130, 170), (190, 240), (270, 190).

Comment: Pointers are not there in JAva i guess. How do i proceed? And How it is `cos(Beta/2)`? i think its `cos(Beta)` and same for other.

Comment: Sorry typo :) will fix. Just pass in an array.

Comment: Will info you about the result.

Comment: I see this `d` value indicates the degree shift. And `v_dot(m0, m1)` will fetch `s`. what does this value of `s` define? is it a distance between 2 points?

Comment: `d` is the perpendicular distance of the polygon to your path. `s` is the distance between `P[n]` and `Q`. glad to hear it worked out.

Comment: if `d` varied then polygon size will also varied (as per my observation). `d` is in what units? km/miles/cm?

Comment: @ShreyasRaoB yes you need to specify `d` as a property of the polygon. in computer geometry everything is relative, so `d` is in the _same_ units as your path geometry (but the idea of units is defined by _you_)

Comment: Could you help me in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782168/need-a-sector-based-on-bearing-geopoint-distance-and-angle)